# Fictional cultures and languages existing in the same area?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, characters, world-building, readers

So I've got this fantasy planet X, where humanoid peoples Y and Z are at war on an island nation about the size of England, and they've been at war with each other for hundreds of years.  They are two very distinct peoples, with different physical appearances, traditions, religions, languages, customs, and the like.

Is it realistic to say that they can still be so rigidly different and still warring with each other after hundreds of years, without any kind of cultural diffusion?  Will readers buy the concept of two cultures living in such close proximity but being so drastically dissimilar, and remaining that way for a long time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this really belongs on the Worldbuilding.SE.

Comment: I don't think [worldbuilding.se] would accept this question. I believe they'll close it as "opinion-based".

Comment: It actually sounds like England...

Comment: I understand that it might not look like exactly the same situation as you're describing it, and the two sides have come to terms for the most part now, but it's my understanding that the situation you describe is not only something that could happen, but something like that did happen, on an island the size, shape, and location of England. Sure, there was some diffusion, but it's my understanding that each period of peace before last century was always a very tenuous thing.

Comment: About the size of England... well, it's not like they were always a United Kingdom...  and if you believe that, I have "A Modest Proposal" for you. To paraphrase Groundskeeper Willie, The Scots and the Irish have been natural enemies.  Like the Scots and the English.  Or the Scots and the Welsh. Or the Scots and the Japanese.

Comment: If they're living together on a small island (not that England is all that small), the chances are that their culture is quite similar but they're in constant struggle over their remaining differences. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism_of_small_differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Readers will buy anything, if you can sell it.** Vampires, wizards, talking animals, superpowers, sentient flat figures... Readers don't look for a realistic story. They look for a *good* story. Any premise will be accepted, if that's what is needed to tell your story, and if your story is good.

Take *House* as an example: the premise requires a doctor so caustic, that in real life he would never have been allowed to keep his practice. Also, most of what they actually do is plain wrong. Does anybody care? No, because the story is good. (Or at least, good enough.)

One thing you do need to keep in mind is consistency. If your setting is not internally consistent, that's like a hole in your sales pitch - everything starts to fray around it. Whatever your setting is, you're asking the readers to suspend their disbelief, and accept your setting as is. Which the reader is ready to do. But the moment you start to contradict yourself, you punch a hole in that suspension of disbelief - the reader cannot simultaneously accept two contradicting prepositions.

**So long as your story is internally consistent, any setting whatsoever is fine.**

If you're still uncomfortable about a particular element, you can try to justify it within your story, but that is risky: you would be drawing attention to where the fabric of the story is weakest. Sometimes it's best to ignore the hole, accept it as part of what's necessary to make your story work. Like the *House* example.

Answer (score 2):

## They don't recognise each other as human

It isn't uncommon for humans to disregard the humanity of races that don't look similar to them. With no shared languages and distinct physicality it is entirely possible that both races regard the other as more akin to apes or cattle.

This is less of a "war" and more "pest-control". Each race views the other as somehow lesser and it has never occurred to them to try peace. With so little regard for the other race, cross-breeding and cultural diffusion is unlikely.

Answer (score -1):

if you look at all the longest running conflicts on planet Earth, they are always always between highly similar cultures/peoples

Christianity vs Islam

Christianity vs Judaism

Islam vs Christianity

Islam vs Judaism

Judaism vs Christianity

Judaism vs Islam

Catholic vs Protestant

Protestant vs Catholic

Japanese vs Korean

Korean vs Japanese

In fact it is difficult for wildly dissimilar cultures to sustain an overly long war.

Comment: Why did you list each conflict twice? That seems really redundant. And can you explain how and why this might be the case? That's what OP is interested in.

Comment: because...  I don't want people to get the impression that i am trying to convey the notion that one is the aggressor  ...  the other is the victim..  And It is directly relevant because...  our worst enemies, are almost always people who look most like us...  So clearly that answers his question about how to sustain a long war between to vastly different cultures.    I am saying that kind of conflicts are virtually nonexistent on earth.

Comment: If we have to limit conflicts geographically "on an island nation about the size of England" then I can think only about Palestine, and even that conflict wasn't flaring for centuries.

Comment: @Alexander: oh why do you think i threw in  Catholic vs Protestant?    have you heard of a place of Ireland?

Comment: Ireland (particularly Northern Ireland) is fresh in our memory, but real trouble there started only in 1960s. In other places, Catholic vs Protestant feuds burned out centuries before (like in XVI century France).

Comment: @Alexander:  so?  Look at history...  all the super long wars are in the Abrahamic religions regions..  the reason is you have to be sufficiently similar to have an argument.

Comment: @ashleylee please give us some examples. Peoples should live within a few hundreds km range, without major natural boundaries and be in an on and off war for 200+ years without reconciliation at sight.

Comment: @Alexander: you are BAD at history and argumentative as hell..   Sunni vs. Shiite.  The crusades...    Let me guess.. you are a liberal progressive gen Xer with a mediocre education background?

Comment: @ashleylee Sunni vs. Shiite agree. Crusades - no, because bases of power had significant geographical separation.

Comment: @Alexander: wrong again.  the separation was nonexistent.  The crusades happened before the fall of Constantinople in 1453.......  For over a thousand years, the muslim empire ran right up against European Christendom...  In fact one of the greatest sackings of Constantinople was committed by the crusaders against their Greek orthodox host (simply because Constantinople were rich and conveniently located)   FYI..  after the fall of Constantinople, Islam pressed right up against central Europe..

Comment: @ashleylee I don't see how this is relevant - Constantinople was never a power base for the crusades. If you are talking about conflicts between Muslim states and Byzantium before crusades, those were regular power struggles between the neighbors, intermittent with peace truces and alliances.